# How do you say "the <device> is broken/doesn't work" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción

So I'm trying to translate sentences like (I'll write the English sentence and then what I think would be a good translation):

> The computer doesn't work.
>   El computador no funciona.

and

> My car does have an air conditioner but it's broken.
>   Mi auto sí tiene aire acondicionado, pero está malo.

I'm not sure if they are correct, but are there other ways to say these?

Note: Don't change/edit "malo" for "roto". I'm a native Spanish speaker and I know it's correct, besides the purpose of the question was to find more ways to say it. But thanks for adding accent marks.

Comment: I'd say "esta malo" is more like "it has gone bad", it still conveys the meaning you wanted it to, I believe.

Answer (score 6):

Your first sentence is fine, **funcionar** is the verb used to mean *to work*<sub>(= operates/functions properly)</sub>.

In the second one, while the sense is mostly conveyed, using *malo* could just be interpreted to mean that it's not the greatest, rather than that it's broken.  There are a number of different verbs used whose participle you can use that work well.  These include *estropear*, *averiar*, *descomponer*,  *romper*, amongst others.  To use these in the sentence you had you would say

> Mi auto sí tiene aire acondicionado, pero está [ **estropeado** | **averiado** | **descompuesto** | **roto** ].

Answer (score 1):

They are correct, indeed. Some other ways include:

> La pantalla de mi computadora esta rota.
>
> My computer screen is cracked.

---

> Te prestaría mi teléfono, pero se ha quebrado cuando se cayó al piso.
>
> I'd let you borrow my phone, but it has broken when it fell on the floor.

---

> Mi auto tiene aire acondicionado, pero no enciende.
>
> My car has air conditioner, but it's not turning on.